# ZEPPELIN: Could not find or load main class org.apache.zeppelin.server.ZeppelinServer

Tags: hadoop, apache-zeppelin

I have

```
OS Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)
Ambari Version 2.5.1.0
HDP 2.6
```

Tried to start Zeppelin Server returned error:

```
    raise ExecutionFailed(err_msg, code, out, err)
resource_management.core.exceptions.ExecutionFailed: Execution of '/usr/hdp/current/zeppelin-server/bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh start >> /var/log/zeppelin/zeppelin-setup.log' returned 1.
```

after step

```
2018-02-28 22:09:17,946 - Execute['/usr/hdp/current/zeppelin-server/bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh start >> /var/log/zeppelin/zeppelin-setup.log'] {'user': 'zeppelin'}
```

In log found exception:

```
ZEPPELIN_CLASSPATH: ::/usr/hdp/current/zeppelin-server/lib/interpreter/*:/usr/hdp/current/zeppelin-server/lib/*:/usr/hdp/current/zeppelin-server/*::/usr/hdp/current/zeppelin-server/conf
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.zeppelin.server.ZeppelinServer
```

How solve this problem?

Comment: Sounds like you're missing the main JAR file under `/usr/hdp/current/zeppelin-server/lib`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked folder

```
/usr/hdp/current/zeppelin-server
```

erased folders /conf

reinstall zeppelin:

```
yum erase zeppelin
```

after more installed

`yum install zeppelin`

Tried more start Zeppelin - OK